# Show only last record with specific field data in access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

My SQL skills are quite basic, but I'm trying to set a database of not-profits for a small business. 
I have a table (extract_financial) with financial data:

```
regno (organisation registration number, unique),
fystart (date, financial year start),
fyend (date, financial year end),
income,
exped (expenditure).
```

Each organisation will have a few records for different financial years. Not all records include income and expenditure values.

I want to show only one record per organisation (including regno, fyend, income), the latest one which has any income.

I've tried the following script, adapted from a similar question, but it didn't work:

```
SELECT ef.regno, ef.fyend, ef.income  
FROM extract_financial ef  
    INNER JOIN  
    (  
        SELECT regno, Max(fyend) AS MaxOfFyend  
        FROM extract_financial  
        GROUP BY regno  
    ) AS efx  
        ON ef.regno = efx.regno   
            AND ef.fyend = efx.MaxOfFyend  
WHERE ef.income IS NOT NULL
```

The query to find the latest entry for each [regno] works, but the problem is that the latest record never has any income in it... So I guess I need an IF THEN?

Would appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.  The `WHERE` clause needs to go in the subquery:

```
SELECT ef.regno, ef.fyend, ef.income  
FROM extract_financial as ef INNER JOIN  
     (SELECT regno, Max(fyend) AS MaxOfFyend  
      FROM extract_financial as ef
      WHERE ef.income IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY regno  
     ) AS efx  
     ON ef.regno = efx.regno AND ef.fyend = efx.MaxOfFyend;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, and apologies for the late response. When trying this script I'm asked to enter a parameter for ef.income and for ef.MaxOfFyend. Any thoughts?

Comment: Working now, after the edit - thanks so much for your help @Gordon !